# How do I diagnose a blocked connection to an internet webserver?

Tags: nginx, firewall, proxy, http-status-code-403

When I browse to three specific sites (which happen to be run by the same provider), I get a *403 Forbidden* Nginx error. However, the sites are up.

- I am able to access the sites  when I use a proxy such as Hola or Tor to access the servers from a different network location.
- I am able to access the sites when I use two other ISPs than my usual.
- An admin of one of the sites reports that the problem does not occur with other users.
- The problem  occurs in multiple browsers and devices.
- No other sites are blocked.

Apparently, something is blocking the connection with this specific ISP and this specific hosting service (run by a small web development company). The sites are not controversial, and in any case I have no reason to think that there is any sort of censor lurking on my connection.

What diagnostic tools can I use to figure out where the blockage is occuring?

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver(s) of the websites you cannot access? It sounds like the block is at the server side if you're getting a 403.

Comment: @Dayvo. Yes, it does look like the block is server-side, but I can access them through a proxy like Hola or  Tor; or with other ISPs than my usual one. Other users can access them.

Comment: Dayvo's question is more likely can you access the logs, and edit the config if necessary on the servers you can't directly access. You should check (and demonstrate) that you're _actually_ trying to talk to the same server you think you are.

Comment: @JoshuaFox It's possible that the server is explicitly blocking you? If you have access to the servers then you could check for the response that you're receiving in the logs and work backwards from there really.